# In TI reference design, why the gnd1 and gnd2 of isolater connect with a cap?

Tags: power-supply

[image]

In this circuit, the gnd1 and gnd2 connected with a cap c27, why?

Comment: Where did you get that? The data sheet doesn't show such a capacitor is needed. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7141cc.pdf

Comment: @Passerby: Its not in datasheet, but I have seen this in most of the isolation based designs, trying to find out the exact reasons, though it is used to couple the ac pulsating noise currents from one ground to another.

Comment: Have you read the app note, and if they mention it? Probably is a capacitive coupling of two grounds, the voltage differnece between them can't be unlimited, perhaps they use this cap to reference the GND2 potential.

Comment: Oddly enough, TI's white sheets on Mixed Signal Grounding also doesn't show them. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt499/slyt499.pdf http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt512/slyt512.pdf

Comment: Check the example on page 2 of the app note. http://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0159.pdf

Answer (score 5):

It's not really to do with the isolator- but you'd typically use a DC-DC converter with such an isolator, and the capacitor is usually needed to conduct switching noise from the switchmode power supply back to the input.

Edit: See the document "Cantrell, Mark. Application Note [AN-0971](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-0971.pdf), Recommendations for Control of Radiated Emissions with isoPower Devices. Analog Devices." referenced in the back of the document AKR linked to- they use the term 'stitching capacitance' because it joins ('stitches') together two isolated ground planes for RF. Note that the capacitor is a single point failure for the isolation barrier so it must be a safety-rated type such as Y rated if a breach of the isolation barrier could cause a safety issue.